# Rational roots of a polynomial with integral coefficients and constant term 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the problem I am working on from Hardy "A course of Pure Mathematics."

Given the polynomial with integral coefficients $x^n+p_1x^{n-1}+p_2x^{n-2} + \cdots + p_n = 0$, with $p_n=1$, and neither of $1+p_1+p_2+ \cdots$, $1-p_1+p_2-p_3, \cdots$ is zero, show that the equation cannot have a rational root.

I have a few observations.  First, I see that any rational root must be an integer.  Also, any integral root must divide 1, so the only possible roots are +1 and -1.  Finally, if neither of the two expressions are zero, then neither is their product.  I've tried using this last fact to reach a contradiction, but with no success.

Comment: You have shown that any possible rational root must be $\pm 1$. You're done, as $1+p_1 + \cdots$ is not zero, nor is $1-p_1+\cdots$, which are the exact expressions you get for using $\pm 1$. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your polynomial, and evaluate it with $x = 1,-1$.  Given what you've said so far, the answer should become clear fairly quickly.